# rotate_sprite rotation is ~65625 times too small

Tags: c++, sprite, image-rotation, allegro, c++98

I'm using c++98 and Allegro 4 and I'm attempting to use the `rotate_sprite` function.  The [docume](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/4/api/blitting-and-sprites/rotate_sprite)[ntation](http://liballeg.org/stabledocs/en/alleg014.html#rotate_sprite) claims that in the angle parameter, 256 is a full circle and 64 is a right angle.

> ```
> void rotate_sprite(BITMAP *bmp, BITMAP *sprite, int x, int y, fixed angle);
> ```

When testing, I found that the sprite did not rotate, but also found when I significantly increased the parameter I was able to get rotation with the number 4200000 appearing to provide a right angle.

```
rotate_sprite(world, plane, plane_x, plane_y, 4200000 * plane_r);
//plane_r is an int 0 to 3
```

So my question is why does 4200000 yield a right angle when the documentation claims a 64 will yield a right angle?  And what is the actual value of a right angle?  4200000 worked in this instance, but what is the exact number for the future?

Comment: The documentation says that `angle` is fixed point 16.  What are you passing?  You might want to look at this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187713/converting-floating-point-to-fixed-point

Comment: @Matt Oh, thanks. I missed that in the documentation.  I saw `itofix` in the related functions.  I'll try using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `itofix` function is used to turn the integer into a a fixed point 16.16 number, which is the type of the parameter.  So a working version of the sample from above is:

```
rotate_sprite(world, plane, plane_x, plane_y, itofix(plane_r * 64));
```